# Limit query results when counting entities

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

What I want is to count the number of `Employees`, but I'm only interested to know if there are 50 or more `Employees`. If I do a `Count`-operation (see below) and set a `Range` between 0->51, will the query just count up to 51 or will it still count all the `Employees`? I want to know this so that the query doesn't count all of the 1000 employees each time the query is run (would be bad for performance).

```
Query query = pm.newQuery("SELECT count(p) FROM Employees p");
query.setRange(0, 51);
long count = (long) query.execute();
if(count >= skipThreshold)
{
   acceptedEmployees.add(mode);
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `SELECT count(p) FROM Employees p` then that will return one row with one value ... the COUNT, since you asked for the count. Range is pointless in that query. You use range when you have multiple rows (objects) returned by the query.

Comment: Thank you! So what you are saying is that the count will actually count ALL objects (meaning bad performance) and THEN apply the limit, which in this count-case does nothing?

Comment: A COUNT query will do an SQL "COUNT(*)", hence returning an aggregate, hence why range is pointless. See the JDO spec and any decent JDO docs

Comment: Okay, then I understand! Wasn't sure the COUNT-query in JDO/App Engine was even implemented in the same way as a normal SQL-query!

Answer (score 0):

From the [google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/queries#Ranges) :

### Ranges

A query can specify a range of results to be returned to the application. The range indicates which results in the complete result set should be the first and last returned. Results are identified by their numeric indices, with 0 denoting the first result in the set. For example, a range of 5, 10 returns the 6th through 10th results:

```
q.setRange(5, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to understand that you have at least 50 Employees is to use the following Query/Count statements.

```
query = db.Query(Employee)
if query.count(50) == 50 :
    # Means, you have at least 50 or more Employees in your Datastore
```

Happy coding...

Comment: I'm using Java and JDO as seen by the "tags" in my question, this doesn't look like Java/JDO. Also the query you performed in the example, is it keys-only or does it retrieve the "whole" entity?

Comment: Hi well sorry if this was not the answer you were looking for. Not knowing JDO that well I figured that you could translate this raw query in JDO. I have a reference and checked that the count(50) will return as soon as the limit has been reached. So no complete entity scan. Just 50 steps and done.

Comment: Still, I think this query is bad if you only want to count the entities, because the "db.Query(Employee)" will fetch all fields in the entitiy, will it not? A so called keys-only query would be better (however one does that in python). :)

Comment: Hi, like I said. my proposed solution will not cycle through the complete dataset. When you would like to go keys only in Python, then I guess this is what you are looking for:

q = db.Query(Player, keys_only=True)
for result_key in q:
   # result_key is a Key...